# node js socket.io problem that will only respond to the last connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Basically, I know that 'socket.io' is a one-on-one communication between the server and the client.

But when I tried to do it myself, it wasn't

1. Connect to the socket using a chrome browser.
2. Connect to the same page using the secret tab.

in the same situation as described above
If an event occurs on client 1, it works on client 2.

How can I generate an event only on each client?

I connected different rooms to each client.

```
//server
socket.join(`${socket.id}`)
socket.to(`${socket.id}`).emit('event')
```

It will not work anywhere.

Comment: Neither one of your statements make any sense.  `socket.to(\`${socket.id}\`).emit('event')`  should just be `socket.emit('event')`.  If you already have the `socket`, then just use it to send to that client.  And, `socket.join(\`${socket.id}\`)` is trying to join a socket to a room that has its id as the room name, but a socket is ALREADY in such a room so there's no point in doing this.

Comment: Plus, there's no point in wrapping a string in a template by itself as `\`${socket.id}`\` is the same as `socket.id`.  Both are just the same string.

Comment: Why doesn't the event occur when I use "socket.to()"? I hope the event will occur only on one client with socketId.

Comment: `socket.to(room).emit(...)` sends to all sockets in the room EXCEPT the one represented by `socket`.  If you want to send to everyone in the room, then use `io.to(room).emit(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method:

```
socket.to(room).emit(...)
```

sends to all sockets in the room EXCEPT the one represented by `socket`.

If you want to send to everyone in the room, then use this:

```
io.to(room).emit(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Refer below link:**

1.Rooms Concept

https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/

2.Emit cheatsheet

https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).